# Using wp_mail() - verify that email was sent?

Tags: wp-mail

When using `wp_mail()`, is there any way to verify that the email was sent correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have probably found, for [`wp_mail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail):

> A true return value does not automatically mean that the user
>   received the email successfully.

A possible workaround is to add an email address that you have access to in the recipients list, and if the one email address receives the mail you can be reasonably (although not 100%) certain that the message was sent.